# pass value in Boolean Object

Tags: java

```
public class BuildStuff { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        Boolean test = new Boolean(true);     
        Integer x = 343;     
        Integer y = new BuildStuff().go(test, x);        
        System.out.println(y); 
    }  

    int go(Boolean b, int i)   {  
        if(b) 
            return (i/7);  
        return (i/49);  
    } 
}
```

This is from SCJP , I understand that answer is "49", but I have a doubt. When we create an object and pass a value in that object. Let's say: `Dog d = new Dog("tommy");` in this statement d is reference to object Dog and Dog has "name" instance variable set to "tommy". But it doesn't mean `d = tommy`.

However, in case of Boolean, when we passed true in Boolean Object. It sets reference to true. Why it is in case of Boolean? Is there any other class too?

Comment: Look into wrapper classes. [Autoboxing and Unboxing.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 3):

The passed-in `Boolean` `b` can be converted to a primitive `boolean` with an unboxing conversion, resulting in the expression `true` for the `if` statement.

All primitive types have corresponding built-in wrapper classes for them, and Java will unbox/box as necessary.

- Boolean <=> boolean
- Byte <=> byte
- Character <=> char
- Short <=> short
- Integer <=> int
- Long <=> long
- Float <=> float
- Double <=> double

(An unboxing conversion will fail with a `NullPointerException` if the corresponding wrapper class instance is `null`:

```
Boolean test = null;
// NPE
boolean b = test;
```

)

Here's [Java's tutorial on boxing and unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: it's not really a double implication Boolean does NOT <=> boolean
If anything boolean is a subset of Boolean. Boolean.getBooleanValue() <=> boolean.

Comment: `Boolean(value)` is true *if and only if* `value` is true. That means double implication.

Comment: @WillBD Yes, but only in that a `null` reference unboxed results in a `NullPointerException`.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: but my question is when i write "System.out.println(test);" .... output is true....why my value passed in Boolean Constructor is refering to reference variable??

Comment: After re-thinking it for a bit, although the value of one does indeed have an implication for both sides, thus the double implication. I disagree that the object has a double implication on all accounts with the primitive, but because that's really just being nitpicky, I renounced my -1, it's a good answer. :)

Comment: @WillBD: It is a double implication because just as Boolean(true), so is `boolean = true`. It would always be true or false given the internal state. If you are referring to comparing the objects, then no they wouldn't be the same. That being said, the comparison of objects in memory for double implication would be a false tautology anyways. So the double implication still exists.

Comment: @user2985842: Because it is unboxing the value of `true` contained in the `Boolean` object.

Comment: @GI Joe , it's not so much about the comparison in memory between objects in my mind, it's more that when I think about a 'double implication' of two java objects, without any mention of a specific property, I interpret that as every 'piece' of that object has a direct implication with the other side. Where, although boolean would have a direct implicated value in Boolean with .getBooleanValue(). Boolean has much that has no implication for boolean, but again, it's really more of an interpretation of the way you use it.

Comment: Ahhh, again I am wrong. I'm going to leave the comments for a good lesson on humility. Since Java automatically boxes every primitive into it's wrapper it does indeed imply the implication. Sneaky Java. Well, touche'!

Comment: @WillBD: But the only way to get the boolean value out is to call `booleanValue`, thats the unboxing.

Comment: @GIJoe Or assign it to a `boolean`, or pass it to a method that takes a `boolean`.  Both assignment conversion and method invocation conversion will perform unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html): *The Boolean class wraps a value of the primitive type boolean in an object. An object of type Boolean contains a single field whose type is boolean.*

If you have

```
Boolean a = new Boolean(true);
Boolean b = new Boolean(true);
```

`a` and `b` are different objects, but `a.booleanValue()` and `b.booleanValue()` return the same primitive. This can be verified by testing `a == b` versus `a.equals(b)`.

There are other classes like this, viz. Integer, Double, etc. As others have already mentioned, you should look into autoboxing and unboxing.

Comment: so i can say that , Boolean class has instance variable "boolean".. so by calling Boolean constructor , it sets boolean = true

Comment: @user2985842: More or less, yes. More accurately you are boxing up the `boolean` into a `Boolean` object (note the capital B).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The `equals` method in the Boolean class compares the equality of this primitive instance variable (of type `boolean`, small b) to establish whether two `Boolean` objects are equal or not. This is kind of like saying whether two dogs are the same or not based on their name ... if both are named "tommy", you say "yes, same dog". (Just drawing an analogy with the example in your question, this is of course, not a realistic scenario)